# How do I activate picked-up items (rockets, boosts) in racing mode?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

What buttons do you use to activate these one-time-use items on the PS3 and Xbox 360?

Comment: A few things. 0. Welcome to this site! This isn't a forum and things work a little differently here. 1. Almost anybody on the internet can edit any post on this site. Editing posts is almost invariably done to imporve your posts, not engage into power trips. 2. There's no need to have game names in the question title. This site is smart enough to do that automatically where it matters. 3. Please don't call people names. That is all.

Comment: @badp You're speaking to the choir. Just check out the history on this post. You should watch some these people. They clearly went on power trips. And there's no welcome needed. I've been here for a while.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For PS3/Xbox, L3/LS is used to launch the missiles or use the boosts in the GTA Races.

Comment: If L3 is the left thumbstick, then yes that works. At least in the default controller scheme. PS3 should be the same (I'm guessing).

Comment: If you are looking backwards (pressing right stick) then you can fire rockets backwards also. This doesn't affect boosts.

Answer (score -2):

It's L3 to shoot rockets, and it will shoot two rockets at a time.

Comment: This has already been mentioned in a previous [answer here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/136580/4797) and does not add to that answer. As per the [Help Center on what answers are deleted](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers) and this [meta] post: [How do we handle duplicate answers?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/4971/4797) - this could be deleted.